# Why is this.setState not updating in my click function?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update my state by using a click function. However for some reason it is not updating. Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?class Textbox extends

```
Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);
      this.state = {
      text: 'jkjkljkljl'
      }

    }
    handle(event) {
      const myValue = event.target.value;
      this.setState({
        text: myValue
      })
      console.log(this.state)
    }

      render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <textarea className="Textbox" rows="2" cols="30" type = "text" >
            </textarea>
            <button className="postbutton" onClick={this.handle.bind(this)}>Post</button>
           <h1>{this.state.text}</h1> 
        </div>

        );
    }
  }



export default Textbox;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your code that works.

Issue was that you were trying to set the value of the button to the state.

What you should do is setup textarea as a controlled input (have value and onChange setup as I did below) and use that value on click.

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textArea: "",
      text: "jkjkljkljl"
    };
  }
  handle(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({
      text: this.state.textArea
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ textArea: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          className="Textbox"
          rows="2"
          cols="30"
          value={this.state.textArea}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <button className="postbutton" onClick={this.handle.bind(this)}>
          Post
        </button>
        <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to handle a form using React/JSX. There are great libraries for this purpose (React Forms).

This is the proper code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);
      this.state = {
      text: 'Static'
      }

    }
    handleOnChange(event) {
      this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {  
      if (event.keyCode == 13) return this.sendData(); 
    } 

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <form onKeyUp={this.handleOnChange}>
            <textarea className="Textbox" 
               rows="2" cols="30" type="text" 
             >
            </textarea>
            <button className="postbutton" 
              onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                Post
            </button>
            </form>
           <h1>{this.state.text}</h1> 
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In your example, you are binding the state to the root of the button and not the textarea. If you want a static example (whereas the above code changes as you type), you may simply handle the enter key via `if (event.keyCode == 13) return this.sendData()` and remove the onChange.